# ReactJs Server Side Rendering Flickering issue

Tags: reactjs

I'm using ReactJs server-side rendering and before loading page completely page blink for one time. Can anyone tell why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

To understand, let's see some basic facts about server side rendering:

The initial page is served by the server (essentially the markup) and is instantly shown to the user

Post that, additional assets like images,js,css etc are loaded asynchronously.

Once the assets are loaded, the framework (here react) kicks in and replaces the original rendered server page. This is important because now the client routes etc can start working as the app has all the resources.

Now in your case, as soon as the react kicks in it hits the first route and loads the page (lazily) and replaces that one with the server rendered page. This delay (lazy loading of your route; first route) is causing the flickr.

One way to prevent this could be to somehow preload your first route! Not sure how you would do it in react...